# Debugging an App on iPhone Device

Tags: iphone, xcode, debugging

This seemed like a really simple thing to do to me at the beginning. However I couldn't figure it out for myself and I've been looking online for a guide or something for hours to no avail.

I have an app that functions perfectly fine in the simulator however, when run on an iPhone device it crashes ... I am fairly sure it is due to memory issues. However these issues can't be recreated in the simulator. What I want to do is attach the xCode Debugger to the App while I'm running it on the phone. I have a certificate and profile and everything already. I have no problems installing and running the app on the phone. However I can't seem to attach the debugger to it.

Any tips?

Comment: What's going wrong when you try to debug on the phone?

Comment: What happens when you select Build and debug?

Comment: I get a whole bunch of errors in the device console resembling this:     Fri Jan 28 11:23:59 Paymans-iPhone com.apple.debugserver-48[5937] <Warning>: 19 [1731/0803]: error: ::task_for_pid ( target_tport = 0x0103, pid = 5938, task => 0x0000 ) 0x000001f5/0x000001f5 0x000001f5/0x000001f5 err = (os/kern) failure (0x00000005)